# Parallel Stages with parallel input message in Jenkins pipe line

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have the following pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('CI') {
            parallel {
                stage('גמלאות') {
                    steps {
                       input message: "Pass Sanity?"
                    } 
                }
                stage('וועדות') {
                    steps {
                       input message: "Pass Sanity?"
                    } 
                }
                stage('מבוטח') {
                    steps {
                       input message: "Pass Sanity?"
                    } 
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

I'm expecting to see in the UI 3 option to select in each stage. but getting only one instead.
If I will look at tradinall console then I will be able to select if to proceed or to abort.
Is there a way to get this function thru the UI?
Here is an example of the UI:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your code implements a proceed or abort for each of three stages. What are the three options you expect for each stage? "Is there a way to get this function thru the UI?" What function do you mean?

Comment: I'm expecting this job to be finish only if all three options were proceed. If one press abort , all should be aborted. Nevertheless, I would like to see like in picture one 3 different popups when hovering over each stage.

Comment: For the former, you would not be able to execute the stages in parallel. For the latter, that would occur after the code is corrected for the first issue.

Comment: They actually are running in parallel. My problem is only the popup message. The stages are represent teams. Each team should press the proceed button before we can continue. Think of it as 3 green lights before we can continue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the code is correct. The problem is with the Jenkins plugin.
I mooved to work with Blueocean plugin, and now it seems to work fine:
[image]